# How can I filters multiple objects in given array using node.js

Tags: node.js

If I Convert my All objects in JSON form Then showing the array "Unexpected script " soo can u tell me if i have a Unwanted object in the given array then how can i filters this particular object
not using key and value of the object its possible to filter the particular object
here my code :-

```
 var arr = [
  '{"Topic":"TRACK","SID":"1","GPSlat":"634312740","GPSlong":"104014684","GPSat":"43788","GPSspd":"20","GPShead":"29499222","GPSepoch":"1638451303"}',
  '{"Topic":"TRACK","SID":"1","GPSlat":"634312740","GPSlong":"104014684","GPSalt":"43788","GPSspd":"20","GPShead":"29499222","GPSepoch":"1638451303"}',
   "{'143567890'}",
  '{"Topic":"TRACK","SID":"1","GPSlat":"634312740","GPSlong":"104014684","GPSalt":"43788","GPSspd":"20","GPShead":"29499222","GPSepoch":"1638451303"}',
  '{"Topic":"Impact","SID":"1","GPSlat":"634312740","GPSlong":"104014684","GPSalt":"43788","GPSspd":"20","GPShead":"29499222","GPSepoch":"1638451303"}'
 
];
```

my code:-

```
let output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  var ReplaceData = arr[i].replace(/\\/g,''); 
  var Finaldata=JSON.parse(ReplaceData);
 
  console.log
   (Finaldata.GPSlat,Finaldata.GPSlong,Finaldata.SID,"11111111111",Finaldata);
}
```

my output:-

```
"634312740", "104014684", "1", "11111111111", {
  GPSat: "43788",
  GPSepoch: "1638451303",
  GPShead: "29499222",
  GPSlat: "634312740",
  GPSlong: "104014684",
  GPSspd: "20",
  SID: "1",
  Topic: "TRACK"
}
"634312740", "104014684", "1", "11111111111", {
  GPSalt: "43788",
  GPSepoch: "1638451303",
  GPShead: "29499222",
  GPSlat: "634312740",
  GPSlong: "104014684",
  GPSspd: "20",
  SID: "1",
  Topic: "TRACK"
}
"Script error."
```

showing the error and stop my loop soo how can i fixed this error ..

Comment: @RickyMo i have a json object soo first when i try to convert then showing the error if i try to filter then say try to convert this object into JSON and then filter soo please see my question clearly

Comment: Please ask your question clearly. If your code throws error, please post the error message and the stack trace so that people know which line of code causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't even state your criteria of filtering. If I have to guess I guess you want to filter out the third element, which is not a valid JSON. You can wrap `JSON.parse()` in a try/catch block to silent the JSON parse error, return a `null` then filter it out.

```js
const arr = [
  '{"Topic":"TRACK","SID":"1","GPSlat":"634312740","GPSlong":"104014684","GPSat":"43788","GPSspd":"20","GPShead":"29499222","GPSepoch":"1638451303"}',
  '{"Topic":"TRACK","SID":"1","GPSlat":"634312740","GPSlong":"104014684","GPSalt":"43788","GPSspd":"20","GPShead":"29499222","GPSepoch":"1638451303"}',
   "{'143567890'}",
  '{"Topic":"TRACK","SID":"1","GPSlat":"634312740","GPSlong":"104014684","GPSalt":"43788","GPSspd":"20","GPShead":"29499222","GPSepoch":"1638451303"}',
  '{"Topic":"Impact","SID":"1","GPSlat":"634312740","GPSlong":"104014684","GPSalt":"43788","GPSspd":"20","GPShead":"29499222","GPSepoch":"1638451303"}'
 
];

const output = arr.map( it => {
  try{
    return JSON.parse(it)
  }
  catch(e){
    return null
  }
}).filter(it => !!it);
console.log(output);
```